# Docker containers don't start automatically unless although having --restart=always flag

Tags: docker, containers, restart, reboot

I have five docker containers running in computer. After restart computer docker images and processes are missed. I have to run "service docker restart" to see images. After I wrote "service docker restart" I  can see dockers with "docker ps -a" command. However, I have "--restart==always" flag for each container. I guess docker service does not start automatically. Is there any suggestion or idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on the distro you use, there are several options to automatically start the docker daemon on boot up of the machine. See [Configure docker to start on boot](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot) for Linux options.

Added this as an answer since I do not have the reputation yet to add a comment...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried  "sudo systemctl enable docker" command for ubuntu 18.04 it doesn't give any error. However after reboot, the situation still same. In my case, also "service docker start" doesn't bring images, I have to write "service docker restart" command. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Mh, this is strange since it is working perfectly fine on my side with Ubuntu 18.04. Is there maybe any dependency that your containers (mapped in stuff etc.) have that are not met at the time the daemon starts? Did you check journal logs since the reboot (`journalctl -b`)?